# Need help translating 破魔の霊気を纏える

Tags: meaning, translation

Full sentence is

> これは副作用ではなくて効能と言えるかもしれないが、破魔の霊気を纏えるようになる。

I don't have problem with first part, but for second part I have no idea. First of all I can't find meaning of verb 纏える. And I'm not sure how 破魔の霊気 should be translated...

Comment: 纏える is the potential form of 纏う. This should be in any dictionary: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%BA%8F%E3%81%86%EF%BC%8F%E7%B5%A1%E3%81%86 Without further context I can only guess at what 破魔の霊気 means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **破魔**: smiting evil, banishing demon, exorcism
- **霊気**: aura, spiritual power, spiritual energy field
- **纏える**: the potential form of the transitive verb 纏う "to wear (coat, aura, ...)"

> 破魔の霊気を纏えるようになる
> [you/someone/one] will be able to wear an evil-smiting aura.

But note that appropriate translations for fantasy terms like 破魔 and 霊気 can vary greatly from work to work. There may be translations that better fit the atmosphere of the work you're reading.